# Google Maps API geocoding service does not work when &language=nl is used in calling the API

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, geocoding

I am working on a project where a user types in a location and Google Maps is queried to get geocoding results using

```
'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=xml&q=' . $address
```

It is processed using

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
```

And later, the results are returned by

```
    if ($xml->Response->Status->code == GOOGLE_GEOCODING_API_XML_SUCCESS_RESPONSE_CODE)
    {
        $coordinates = explode(",", $xml->Response->Placemark->Point->coordinates);

        if ($coordinates)
        {
            return array(
            $coordinates[0],
            $coordinates[1]
            );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
```

Then, the user selects a result from the dropdown and some fields like Address, State, ZIP code are filled automatically.

The code works fine if no language parameter is passed. Our client would like the map to be in a particular language, but setting that causes the autocomplete functionality to stop.

I've tried:

1. Changing the language, country code biasing of returned results to the desired language and country
2. Putting `alert()` at various steps of the JavaScript code indicates that with the &language parameter set, no results are being returned from the http geocoding request.
3. Using version 3 of Google Maps API for the http geocoding request.

Kindly guide how to proceed and solve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wrong URL.Try these:

**JSON**:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Amsterdam&language=nl

**XML**:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=Amsterdam&language=nl

[**Documentation here**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Comment: I think this is API version 3, while the code in project is using version 2. The autocomplete works fine with that also when &language=nl is not passed while loading the map [http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false]. Maybe the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: The URLs I posted are for a web service. You call them from the server side and then parse the reply and use the data as you wish, so they are version agnostic.